# Bitmap color everything non transparent

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I am very unfamiliar with image processing and i more or less need to remove the background of an image and then color everything else remaining with a random color.

I've managed to succesfully remove the background and turn it transparrent however i now need to color everything else remaining.

Here is the image before i make it transparrent and the result afterwards.
Now i simply need to color everything that is remaining however i have zero clue how would be able to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, you only need to check the [alpha component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description) of a pixel to know whether it is (partially) transparent or not. However, typically, if you work with some proper image library, you would first create a mask or selection based on some criteria (e.g., background color), then using the mask to make the background transparent as well as coloring the other parts of the image (based on the inverse mask). If you have to deal with partial transparencies or anti-aliasing artifacts, well things would get more complicated then...

Comment: Remove the background, make it transparent and color the rest. What is the expected result ???